# Using a State Variable in Boolean Statement in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a state variable in a swiftUI view `@State private var value: Int`. When I use that state in boolean statements like so `value == 10` it doesn't update if passed to a second view.

E.g the highliting in the following never changes:

```
struct TestView: View {

   @State private var value = 5
   var body: some View {
    
       Button("update value") {
           withAnimation { value = value + 5 }
       }
    
       Text("\(value)").padding()

       MyTestView(highlighted: value == 5).padding()
       MyTestView(highlighted: value == 10).padding()
       MyTestView(highlighted: value == 15).padding()
   }
}

struct MyTestView: View {
   @State var highlighted: Bool = false

   var body: some View {
       Text("test")
          .background(highlighted ? Color.red : Color.white)
   }
}
```

Comment: your second edit on question has different of night and day! what an exact question you asked for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple Developer Documentation:

> SwiftUI manages the storage of any property you declare as a state. When the state value changes, the view invalidates its appearance and recomputes the body. Use the state as the single source of truth for a given view.

So, when your State wrapped value changes, the body will be recalculated. In your example above, you are not  showing anything that would change your State value. When creating your View for the first time, the compiler will check the first value of your variable "value" and then set your Text accordingly. To make updates to that text, you have to change your State variable.

```
Button(action: {
    //Here you update your State variable, which will force the body to recalculate
    self.value = 15
})
{
    Text("Update variable")
}
```

**Edit:**

As you now posted your code, here is the solution. You do not need to declare `highlighted` as `State` in your `MyTestView`. Just declare it as `var`, and it will work. As Apple says, declare your State values private, to not change them from outside. Here, in your example, State is not correct, because you dont change that value from inside your body.

```
struct MyTestView: View {
   var highlighted: Bool = false

   var body: some View {
       Text("test")
          .background(highlighted ? Color.red : Color.white)
   }
}
```

**Edit to show up a solution using Binding**

There is a solution using binding, however this will change your logic and it is not really necessary in your use cases as discussed in the comment:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var value = 5
    var body: some View {
    
        Button("update value") {
            withAnimation { value = value + 5 }
        }
    
        Text("\(value)").padding()

        MyTestView(highlighted: $value, border: 5).padding()
        MyTestView(highlighted: $value, border: 10).padding()
        MyTestView(highlighted: $value, border: 15).padding()
   }
}

struct MyTestView: View {
    @Binding var highlighted: Int
    var border : Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
            .background(highlighted == border ? Color.red : Color.white)
    }
}
```

Will give you the same effect, however not really well

Comment: @davidev, Binding would be the right answer not what you answered here! it is wrong answer! I do NOT know how could your answer be a right answer!

Comment: @Omid I don't know why you would use Binding in that case. You are not changing a value in MyTestView. From Apple documentation: "Use a binding to create a two-way connection between a property that stores data, and a view that displays and changes the data." If you would change the value inside MyTestView and wants updates to your Parent View you would use Binding. Like a Toggle button, which sends updates of the State to their parent

Comment: @davidev, see the code he camper something for rendering a View,   value == 5, value == 10, value == 15! Your explaining about Binding is not full explaining take a look to apple website for more info, if he would just call MyTestView on time and after that would not need to update that view I could understand your answer, but as you see he starts changing the value highlighted in TestView! IT MEANS MyTestView should update itself also! your understanding of Binding is wrong, "to create a two-way connection" that is part of Job of Binding Not all

Comment: Show me your code with Binding ;) The thing is, Binding is used when you change the value inside your SecondView and want to refresh in the parent view. There are example with ModalView, pushing views, where you change the variable in the child and the parents refreshes. But what are you changing here in your child (MyTestView). You are not changing the variable there. You are just reading from the parent. Your parent is not refreshing. This is the other way around

Comment: I also had the understanding that bindings are for 2-way changes and therefore opened this question because I thought using a binding even tho it works is not correct. So, @Omid what is the benefit of a binding over the solution davidev gave?

Comment: I edit the answer, just to show you a solution with binding. However, you need to refactor your logic and binding still doesn't make any sense, because you are not changing that value inside your child view. Watch Apple example here of Binding. They are changing the value inside the child view, which refreshes the parent view. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

Comment: @lenny, plz next time take a good time before accepting an answer. If I want gave u a simple example about the issue, would be difference between a constants and variables! If you use his method your view would be like a constants! you would not be able update it later on! But if you chose Binding, your View would be like a variables! You could update that view later on! I am seeing your code, that you are changing value in Button action! So you have to use Binding for re-act to your Button! I just tried to give you simple understanding here.

Comment: @Omid I really do appreciate your effort and willing to help me! Thx a lot. But I have to admit that the code I've shown is just an example to demonstrate the issue I had. In reality it's indeed the case that the subview has no control about wheather it's highlighted or not. That's why I used State rather than Binding. So in my particular case I still think this is the correct answer.

Comment: Also on this platform, you better make quick decisions. Just within the hour I noticed my initial example was bad and came up with an improved one I recieved enought dislikes and close requests to better hurry up before it gets closed ^^